# Fixed column scroll table

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I have a scroll table (you can see a example in the img). 
In the last column I have buttons to do an action

I would like to fix this column and shake the rest.

I knew I had to use position (absolute), but if I put the keys out of it.
Do you know a way to fix the last column and shake the rest?

[image]

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Can I show your coding??

Comment: Unfortunately it is a table that you create with react. The html code is created automatically. I can change the css, html ecc.

Css for table is :

<code>
.table-scrollbar {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
<code>


If it was possible to have a small example of how to do it

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

table {
  background: yellow;
}

.fixed {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th class="fixed">Year</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td class="fixed">1970</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Madrid</td>
    <td class="fixed">1940</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<br>
<p>To test, scroll orizontally</p>
```